# How to make a certain script run on 'permission denied'? (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, espeak

I have had an idea for a bash script on my Pi that uses espeak to say "I'm sorry $username, I'm afraid I can't let you do that", when you try to do something you don't have permission for.

However, I have no idea how to do this, and a minimal knowledge of Bash, so any advice would be useful.

Comment: I don't believe that's something you can act on that way. You'd need a fairly invasive injection to be able to do this.

Comment: Permission denying happens at the kernel level, so there'd have to be something installed in the kernel that would trigger every time there was a denied permission. SELinux may have something like this, although I'm fairly sure there are many different types of "permission denied" and so you may have to limit yourself to file permissions.